# Fetch Assoc - Add Data to Array Once Per ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm querying a simple database and I'm using the following PHP code...

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

    if($row["status"] == 1) {
        $total[] = $row["to_win"];
    }

    print_r($total);

}
```

The current data structure looks like this...

```
id          to_win          status
1           1200.00         1
2           238.94          2
3           1850.57         1
4           55.00           2
5           127.85          2
```

The problem is it seems that each time it gets another row, it adds the $total to the array. As a result, my print_r is this...

```
Array ( [0] => 1200.00 ) Array ( [0] => 1200.00 ) Array ( [0] => 1200.00 ) Array ( [0] => 1200.00 [1] => 1850.57 ) Array ( [0] => 1200.00 [1] => 1850.57 ) Array ( [0] => 1200.00 [1] => 1850.57 ) Array ( [0] => 1200.00 [1] => 1850.57 ) Array ( [0] => 1200.00 [1] => 1850.57 )
```

Could I just have it add it one time per ID so that the array would contain one 1200.00 and one 1850.57 rather than multiple entries?

Thanks!

Comment: in the last `print_r` output you have the desired two entries in your array. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is as expected. But I guess you want to place the `print_r()` outside of the loop: ;)

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["status"] == 1) {
        $total[] = $row["to_win"];
    }
}

print_r($total);
```

---

But however, as this was easy, I'll give you another advice. Results that are coming from database queries are strings although the SQL column type might be INTEGER. Although in *this* short example it will work as you wish it is a good practice to check for the correct type. So the statement should be:

```
if($row["status"] === '1')
```

Comment: or better yet just add `where status = 1` to the query